# Name mangling example in Python tutorial

Tags: python, oop, private-members, name-mangling

Refer to section [*9.6 Private Variables*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) where this example is given for the __name mangling feature of Python:

```
class Mapping:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.items_list = []
        self.__update(iterable)

    def update(self, iterable):
        for item in iterable:
            self.items_list.append(item)

    __update = update   # private copy of original update() method

class MappingSubclass(Mapping):

    def update(self, keys, values):
        # provides new signature for update()
        # but does not break __init__()
        for item in zip(keys, values):
            self.items_list.append(item)
```

*The above example would work even if `MappingSubclass` were to introduce a `__update` identifier since it is replaced with `_Mapping__update` in the `Mapping` class and `_MappingSubclass__update` in the `MappingSubclass` class respectively.*

I understand how this works: when the `Mapping` class uses `self.__update(iterable)`, it's calling its own definition of `update` and explicitly opting-out of calling any subclass method. Without that indirection, a subclass redefinition would have caused a broken `__init__` method, raising:

```
TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'
```

What I don't understand is *why* it would ever be done in this obscure way, when a more clear and direct way of doing the same thing would be:

```
class Mapping:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.items_list = []
        Mapping.update(self, iterable)

    def update(self, iterable):
        for item in iterable:
            self.items_list.append(item)
```

The mangled namespace behavior seem to complicate the language, particularly in the byte-compiling of CPython, so is there some better explanation about why it's a necessary feature at all? I'm looking for an example that can *only* be achieved using name-mangling, or an explanation of why the contrived example in the docs actually *does* need the mangling and can't be more simply written as described, removing any need for the confusing "Private Variables" feature to be a part of the language at all.

Comment: its just pythons way of providing "privates" (that are not really very private) ... one of the great things about python is that you can ignore the bits you dont need ... nothing is stopping you from implementing the "better" pattern you describe  (but `why` is not something that stackoverflow is very good about answering in general)

Comment: Unfortunately you can't just ignore the bits you don't need, newcomers to Python often write code with all methods name-mangled and then use that section of the tutorial as justification (it's the google result for "private variables python").

Comment: as a lead you make a style doc saying thats forbidden if you dont want it ... newcomers do plenty of things wrong ... its on senior developers to help them out (and sometimes to learn from them ... ) it doesnt really make it harder for a senior developer to work with code that uses this method its just kind of annoying...